# How can i get only employer name using facebook ios API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

here is my code:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,first_name,last_name,picture.width(300).height(300),gender,birthday,work"}]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                fNameUser = [result valueForKey:@"first_name"];
                lNameUser = [result valueForKey:@"last_name"];
                genderUser = [result valueForKey:@"gender"];
                NSLog(@"You Work At: %@", [result valueForKey:@"work"]);
```

and the out put from NSLOG is

```
You Work At: (
        {
        employer =         {
            id = 12345678909876543;
            name = "Employer Name";
        };
        id = 34234234234343455465;
    }
)
```

from this output i just want to get Employer name. how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `[result valueForKey:@"work"]` starts at array at the same time it is in singe index , So I used as `0`

do like

```
NSString *employername = result[@"work"][0][@"employer"][@"name"];
```